# Default value for spring bean property is not working in spring 5

Tags: spring

[1](https://github.com/tapasvisoni/SpringHelloWorld)I created a simple Helloworld program with spring 5. I have a boolean property for a bean. I want to set default value as false if empty value is set for the property.

My properties file with property
My `sample.properties` has

```
sample.boolean=
```

I am expecting, spring will set value of `sample.boolean=false` if `sample.boolean` is empty as shown above.
But it doesnot work and I get `IllegalArgumentException`.
Am I missing something in the configuration??

Please refer to my code in following link for more description
[Code Link](https://github.com/tapasvisoni/SpringHelloWorld)

Comment: I am using <property name="isvalid" value="${sample.boolean:false}" /> in spring configuration file

Comment: I tried with ?: and it seems to work but not : What's wrong with colon

Comment: Rather than add information as comments, could you please put all of the information into your post and include the code that you're referring to rather than bits of code.

Comment: The default value is only applied if the property is not present, you have a property present with a value that cannot be converted to a boolean. NOt present or empty are 2 different things.

Comment: M.Denium , So is there anyway in spring which allows me to convert empty value to some default value

Answer (score 0):

As it was mantainde in comments, property should not be presend. So try to
comment it out

```
# sample.boolean=false
```